# ESP8266 Push button - pin State stay the same

Tags: button, esp8266

Wanted to do some IOT stuff so I bought an ESP8266 (WeMos D1 Mini Pro).

I wanted to send a MQTT message to my server only if I push a button.

I wired on side of the button to the GNR and the other side to D6 (GPIO12).

I set `pinMode(12, INPUT);`

and inside the loop :

```
void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

  boolean pinState = digitalRead(12);

  Serial.printf("Start State: %s",(pinState)?"HIGH":"LOW");
  Serial.println();
  if (pinState == LOW) {
    const char* test2 = "Test";
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(test2);
    client.publish("iPub", test2);
  }
}
```

pinState start at `HIGH` and I can see it looping. When I press the button it change to `LOW` (send the message), enter the if statement and the pin state continue to be `LOW`. So it cannot stop sending a message. But when I release the button the pin should change it's state ?

I tried to add an `pinState = !pinState;` inside the if but the state stay `LOW` after that.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Are you sure the state isn't changing, or is it just that the time taken to go round the loop is significantly quicker than you can push and release the button, so it reads the down state multiple times?

Comment: the state start at HIGH.... when I push the button the message is send XXX times

Comment: You need [pullup/pulldown resistors](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/button) or use [`INPUT_PULLUP `](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/InputPullupSerial)

Comment: @gre_gor can you put your comment as an answer !
You made my day !

Comment: @Ragnar: if you invite an answer, it's customary to accept it. just sayin'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you pull the pin to VCC or GND with resistors, the pin will be floating and can be affected by other pins, wires or even your finger.

You can either use external pulldown/pullup resistor:

[image]

or use the internal pullup:

```
pinMode(12, INPUT_PULLUP);
```